# How to edit a string value result of column values returned by `SELECT` SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have written a query that returns the results that I am looking for, but I would like to only have 'iOS' or 'Android' returned instead of the full `device_info` string.

```
SELECT
  fans.device_info
FROM
  fans
JOIN
  rewards_codes_redemptions ON rewards_codes_redemptions.fan_id = fans.id
JOIN
  rewards_codes ON rewards_codes.id = rewards_codes_redemptions.reward_code_id
WHERE
  rewards_codes.account_id IN ('1580fb29-4c9e-4f6f-9d1c-c06e43a873fb',
                               'edf9984a-5000-44f5-b379-25bb34620c78')
ORDER BY
  rewards_codes_redemptions.created_at
LIMIT
 50
```

CURRENT RESULTS

```
iOS; 11.4.1; iPhone,
Android; 9; Pixel 2 XL
// ...
```

DESIRED RESULTS

```
iOS,
Android
```

Might it be best to do a subquery for each?

Thanks for the help

Comment: just add an `AND fans.device_info IN ('IOS', 'ANDROID')` to the where

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, but the returned results are correct. I just want to remove the operating system version and the device name from the results.

Comment: @DavidSawatske . . . Do you really want a comma after `iOS`?  If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the use of a CASE statement combined with LIKE.

Best when you write that sort of code to get back the original results and add a column for your desired result set.

Case:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp

Like:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a `CASE` statement with in the `SELECT` clause.

```js
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN fans.device_info LIKE '%iOS%' THEN 'iOS'
    WHEN fans.device_info LIKE '%Android%' THEN 'Android'
  END AS device
```

Comment: How about `IOSIS` be your value?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want a comma after `iOS`.  So, let me assume that you just want the string before the first semicolon.

In that case:

```
SELECT (regexp_split_to_array(fans.device_info, ';'))[1] as device
```